# hudson / jenkins - Adding job template type in the New Job page

Tags: templates, plugins, hudson, jenkins, jobs

I'm trying to learn about plugin development in jenkins/hudson,
and I have a task to add a new job template to the current jobs available in the New Job page.
[image: New Job Page]

When auser chooses 'My Job' type, he gets the usual configuration options (for free style job) along with some additional fields I want to add.

First, I would like to know if it's possible to acheive via plugin.
If so, any information/tips you can provide would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved. If someone else needs it, all needs to be done is to take as a reference the FreeStyleProject.java code.